# Php refresh page with message?

Tags: php

I have an edit form with the url looking like `localhost/edit-form/*code*` The code is a random 16 long string. What I would like to do is when submitting the form, refresh the page showing the form again with the new values.

I have tried to redirect with an extra attribute like `localhost/edit-form/*code*/message` which returns an error saying page not found.

I have also tried something like `localhost/edit-form/*code*?message=1` but message isnt available to get via `$_GET`.

My goal is just to have a div alert saying "form edited" after the page is refreshed.

Comment: _“but message isnt available to get via $_GET”_ - no apparent reason why it shouldn’t be; your post does not contain enough information for us to be able to tell what went wrong there. The URL format suggests you have probably some sort of internal URL rewriting in place though, so perhaps the problem lies in that part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash messages are usually stored in `$_SESSION`. You could create a custom method that...

1. Stores the message to the session.
2. Deletes the message from the session, as soon as it is displayed for the user.

You could then call the method in your template file as soon as the user is redirected to it.

Answer (score 0):

After your operation you can store message is $_SESSION['mesaage']

If this variable is set then you can display the message. As an oddon you can store success and failure class in separate session variable and display with success or failure class.

Once text is displayed you can unset sessions.